# Imprimir variable de php en html

Tags: php, html, php7

estoy empezando en php así que disculpa por la pregunta tan simple, pero espero que me puedan ayudar, estoy enviando datos desde un archivo html a un archivo php, luego estoy intentando imprimir una de las variables enviadas en el mismo html de la cual envié, el problema es que me sale como variable indefinida y no se porque en el HTLM y no se porque, ya que se supone que estoy guardando el valor dentro de la variable y después solo la intento imprimir, pero como dije, me aparece como variable indefinida, disculpen por la pregunta tan simple, pero como dije, estoy recién empezando !!

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
    width: 45%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 25px;
}

.title{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

input[type="text"]{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

textarea{
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 320px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.enviar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.753);
    border: none;
}

.exitoso{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(54, 206, 54, 0.979);
    color: white;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.error{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(206, 54, 54, 0.979);
    color: white;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="title">Formulario - Contacto</p>
        <form action="app.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="txtNombre" placeholder="Nombre">
            <input type="text" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Email">
            <textarea name="txtMensaje" placeholder="Ingrese Mensaje"></textarea>
            <?php
                echo $nombre; 
            ?>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="enviar" name="btnEnviar">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Codigo PHP :**

```
<?php

    $nombre = $_POST["txtNombre"]; 
    require "index.php"; 
?>
```

Comment: El código PHP y el HTML están el mismo archivo ?

Comment: No, esta en uno aparte llamado app.php

Comment: Deben estar en el mismo o incluirlo en el html

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Imprimir variables PHP en diferentes lugares en html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90132/imprimir-variables-php-en-diferentes-lugares-en-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas empezando con php debes tener muy en claro el concepto cliente - servidor.

**Problema**

Al momento que se abre tu página index.html la variable $nombre aún no tiene valor, el valor se lo das hasta que presionas el botón entonces pasa a tu archivo app.php el cual le da el valor y te regresa al index el cual lo debería imprimirla.

**Pero el error es básicamente eso, al iniciar, estás haciendo referencia a una variable que no tiene valor aún.**

**Solución**

Valida que te llegue la variable con isset.
hazlo de los dos archivos para que no tengas el problema de variable indefinida

**Ejemplo**

**En tu index.php**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="title">Formulario - Contacto</p>
        <form action="app.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="txtNombre" placeholder="Nombre">
            <input type="text" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Email">
            <textarea name="txtMensaje" placeholder="Ingrese Mensaje"></textarea>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['txtNombre'])) {
                echo $nombre; 
            } 
            ?>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="enviar" name="btnEnviar">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**En tu app.php**

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['txtNombre'])) {
    $nombre = $_POST["txtNombre"]; 
    require "index.php"; 
}
?>
```

**Observaciones**

Ahí lo único que haces es en el index.php preguntar antes si llego la variable $nombre y si es así la imprimes, en app preguntas si llego la variable txtNombre porque es la que le va a llegar ya que así se llama tu caja de texto, es decir así está especificado en su valor "name".
espero que te sirva, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puntos a mencionar:

- Tu formulario tiene una ruta a la cual mandar la información que llenas en los inputs
- Los datos viajan y llegan a dicho archivo que recuperas por medio de la super variable [`$_POST`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.superglobals.php)
- Los valores que mandaste a través de tu formulario ahora viven en el archivo `app.php`
- Dado el contexto de tu ejercicio no tiene caso mandarlos a un archivo externo si después lo tratas de imprimir en el mismo formulario

Propuesta:

En tu formulario, déjalo así:

- Borra la ruta del atributo `action` y solo escribele un comodín (#)
- Dentro del mismo `textarea` recibe el valor por medio de `$_POST` y asignalo a una variable
- Imprime dicha variable y maneja que si el usuario no ingresa nada entonces le aparezca un mensaje haciéndoselo saber por medio del [operador de fusión NULL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php)

---

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="usuario">
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">
        <?php 
            $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];

            echo $usuario ?? "Sin usuario asignado";
        ?>
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Motivo:

- En tu archivo `app.php` en realidad no procesas la data recibida a través de ninguna lógica entonces esta demás